# How to re-enable function keys in byobu?

Tags: gnu-screen, byobu

I was using byobu on Ubuntu 11.10 Server and I needed to hit a function key in an app, so I hit F9 to bring up the config menu and switched the keybinding set from "f-keys" to "screen-escape-keys".  That worked, but now I can't re-enable all the f-keys.

I found a program `byobu-config` that brings up the menu again, and I can switch back to screen keys from there.  This fixes things for new screen processes, but the effect on the current screen session is weird: it disables the CTRL-A (screen) keys and restores F2-F8, but F9-F12 still don't do anything (they're just passed on to the foreground process).

What's up with this?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Since byobu-config fixes things for new screen processes but not the current session it may be a bug worth reporting.

Visit https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu to report the bug or to see if someone else already has.

Optionally you could contact the project maintainer, Dustin Kirkland:
https://launchpad.net/~kirkland

This is not a direct solution to your problem, but should be a step in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

We can try to debug your particular situation, but the easiest solution would be to just clear your current Byobu configuration with:

```
rm -rf ~/.byobu
```

And then restart `byobu`.