# Cannot make function key bindings (F1-F12) to work in byobu with tmux backend

Tags: bash, tmux, key-binding, byobu

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and have the latest version of byobu installed via apt-get. It has always worked flawlessly but started showing some weird behaviour just recently with no obvious reason. I use it with `bash` and `tmux` as the backend.

```
$ byobu --version
byobu version 5.74
tmux 1.8
```

First, `byobu`'s function keys (`F1-F12`) stopped working.
Second, creating a new window (`F2`) or split (`CTRL+F2`), or leaving the opened session (`CTRL+F6`) also stopped working.

My `$TERM` environment variable is reset to `screen` every time I create a new window, split or similar. This causes errors when trying to open `vim` or even running `clear`, for example. Setting the variable manually (`export TERM=xterm-color`) and sourcing my `.bashrc` temporarily fixes the issue.

I deleted the byobu config dir (`rm -rf ~/.byobu`) following [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/359428/how-to-re-enable-function-keys-in-byobu), ran `byobu-config` and changed the escape sequence to `CTRL+A` (the default), but when I open a new window or split the `$TERM` variable is still set to `screen`.

Possibly unrelated issue that appeared at the same time: when I type the `up` key in bash to scroll through the list of previous commands and try to edit the command line, it shows me as if what I type in replaces the existing characters (which is the expected behaviour when the `insert` key is active). Nevertheless, it just appears to do that: what actually happens in the background is the expected (it's just inserting whatever I am typing in where the cursor is).
This does not happen if I don't go to a previous command with the `up` key.

Still, I can't create a new window by typing `F2` but I can create a new split with `SHIFT+F2` or `CTRL+F2`.
I can create a new window, though, by typing `CTRL+A c` (I got the idea from this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/406421/tmux-key-bindings-not-working)).

How to make the keybindings for function keys (F1-F12) work as it used to (default when you press `F1`)?

Answer (score 3):

Since some keybindings work in your `byobu` and some do not, I think it could be an issue with your terminal emulator program.

I just had that case:

- When running `byobu` inside `qterminal`, it would not detect the <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F5</kbd> keybindings. <kbd>F6</kbd> would work fine, though.
- When running `byobu` inside `gnome-terminal`, everything was fine.