# Several byobu commands don't seem to work at all

Tags: command-line, keyboard, thinkpad, byobu, terminal-multiplexer

In a (possibly misguided) attempt to make my ancient netbook (Thinkpad S10e) as fast as possible, I installed a minimal setup of SparkyLinux on it, without an X server. I want to use byobu as a multiplexer, since it seems to be the most user-friendly and have features I actually need.

However, several commands don't seem to work at all. Ctrl-F# never work, although Ctrl-a does. The F12 key also doesn't work, which could be something to do with having to use Fn-F11 to access it, but I'm not too sure. I can't get Midnight Commander to work in byobu either.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For the same problem, but running byobu in a terminal emulator, so _with_ an X server: https://superuser.com/q/1098535